# Gitlab: reset/roll back does not work in pre-receive hook

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I was trying to roll back commit to the previous version when script "Check.py" returns 0 or 1 in pre-receive hook  (please see the following code). My issue is even though "git reset --soft $i^1" did execute, I still see the newest commit on GitLab. What I want to achieve is when $ret equals 0 or 1, I'd like to roll back the commit to the previous one in the current branch.

Thank you all for your help!

```
read oldrev newrev branch

mapfile -t my_array < <(git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev)
 
for i in ${my_array[@]}
do
        git show $i > /tmp/$$.temp
        python /script/Check.py /tmp/$$.temp
        ret=$?
        if [ $ret -ne 2 ]; then
            git reset --soft $i^1
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A pre-receive hook runs *before* some ref names (e.g., `refs/heads/foobranch`) is/are updated.  Its job is to:

- read *all* the lines (you read only one, i.e., you assume just one name is proposed to be updated);
- *inspect* those lines to see whether or not to allow the push to update *all* those names; and
- exit 0 to allow the updates to begin, one at a time, or exit nonzero to reject the entire push.

Your script never has any explicit `exit` so it would exit with the status of the last command run (but see below).  Zero means all the updates are allowed.

Besides this, your script runs `git reset --soft`, which resets the *current branch*, whatever that is.  The current branch is not related to the branches and/or tags being updated by this particular `git push`, except by happenstance.

The most immediate bug, however, is probably this:

> I was trying to roll back commit to the previous version when script "Check.py" returns 0 or 1 ...

Your script checks for `$ret -ne 2`.  The exit status from `python /script/Check.py /tmp/$$.temp` is in `$?`, not `$ret`.  This produces a syntax error, after which bash simply exits (zero, in my test; I found this a bit surprising but it would explain your results).  **Edit**: now that you have `ret=$?`, the script itself will run, but if `HEAD` names a branch that the `git push` updates, and if you allow the `git push` to proceed, the branch name will be updated and the effect of the reset eliminated.  (If you exit nonzero, the reset may take effect, but no push has occurred and that's a bad idea.)

Fixing this will still leave you with the remaining issues.  Fixing *those* requires knowing what you really wanted to achieve, which you have not mentioned here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply torek. My "Check.py" script does have explicit exit. Sorry I accidentally deleted $ret when I was editing my post. What I want to achieve is when $ret equals 0 or 1, I'd like to roll back the commit to the previous one in the current branch, that's the reason I run `get reset --soft` .

Comment: A pre-receive hook *cannot* roll anything back. There's nothing to roll back. It's simply deciding whether or not to *allow `git push` to proceed*.

Comment: You mean pre-receive hook?